# UserControl to display 16x16 or 32x32 images

Tags: wpf, binding, size

I have a control that assembles a final image from multiple PNG files. The individual png files are chosen based on item states bound to the control. i.e.  overlayed - but that all works fine.

Each image file is created in two sizes 16x16 and 32x32 (i.e. like an icon)

From the VS designer (or code) I want the user to be able to specify whether they want the 16x16 or 32x32 version. So I added a dependency property ImgSize. I've made it an int so I can set it to 16 or 32. So a user of this control simply XAMLs

```
<xyz:thisControl ImgSize="32"/>
```

and the DataContext supplies all the binding particulars.

I want the width and height of the user control to be automatically set to the corresponding image size. So binding like so makes sense:

```
<UserControl x:Class="...
    Width="{Binding Path=ImgSize}"
    Height="{Binding Path=ImgSize}"
```

When that didn't work, I tried every RelativeSource binding I could - no luck. Is there an additional layer of plumbing/binding/events I'm missing?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: A more direct way to put this is that I want the control to be available in 2 sizes (as set through the dependency property). When the control is being used in the designer (say in a stack panel) it will be formatted accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use the built-in width and height of the UserControl?

These properties are bindable by default

Comment: Yes, and I can infer which size image to load in the converter - pass in ActualSize as a parameter or something. --- I wanted to (eventually) remove the size-specifics from the user/app and ImgSize would then be Small,Med,Large,XL. And if 'Small' changed from 16x16 to 20x20, none of the code would care. But I tend to get ahead of myself - thanks!